# Mixing handlebars.js and CSS - Random background image?

Tags: css, meteor, handlebars.js

I would like to set a randomly generated background image.

I am using Meteor and am calling Flickr API to provide a random image URL which I would like to set as my background image.

From what I've read, it seems that CSS is now the recommended way to set a background image. Is there a way to inject the dynamically generated url into the CSS? I can't seem to find examples showing mixing of Handlebars.js and CSS - is this possible? Or should I be avoiding CSS and setting the background image using the traditional HTML way?

I've been trying two different strategies:

1) To create the CSS attribute in the HTML with the url injected via handlebars - but I can't seem to concatenate the CSS attribute with Handlebars.

2) The other method I've tried is to create the CSS attribute as a variable in the template code, and to return that into the HTML via Handlebars, like so:

```
Template.backgroundImage.background = function(){
//runs function to generate url and add to Session object   
    FlickrRandomPhotoFromSet(setID);
//create variable with html and css attribute concatenated to url
var backgroundImage = '<div style="background-image: url('+Session.get("RandomURL")+')"></div>';
//return resultant variable to HTML via template
    return backgroundImage;
};
```

Then in the HTML I have inserted the following:

```
<template name="backgroundImage">
    {{background}}
</template>
```

Comment: Is it possibile to mix CSS style attribute info with a {{}} handlebars insertion? I can't seem to get this to work.

Comment: @muistooshort I have expanded the original question with some code examples, hopefully this is more clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This approach ended up working for me:

I'm using an internal stylesheet that I define as a template. The url is updated to match the randomly generated url:

```
<template name="backgroundImage">
  <style>
  body {
  background-image:url({{background}});
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right top;
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Meteor has a package built for meteor called `random` you can add with

```
meteor add random
```

If it is not included in your project already.

The `Random.choice()` method could help you e.g if you have an array of URLs

```
var myurls = ["http://www.url.com/1","http://www.url.com/2","http://www.url.com/3"];
var the_random_url = Random.choice(myurls);
```

Then as you mentioned alter the 'body' with css & a handlebars helper for `{{background}}`

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image:url({{background}});
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: right top;
    }
</style>
```

Or edit it with jquery:

```
$('body').css({
    background-image:"url("+the_random_url+")",
    background-repeat: "no-repeat"
    background-position: "right top"
});
```

Answer (score -1):

sugarjs provides a sample() method

http://sugarjs.com/api/Array/sample

or you can check source to write your own.

https://github.com/andrewplummer/Sugar/blob/master/lib/array.js#L906

Returns a random element from the array. If num is passed, will return num samples from the array.

i use this on my meteor.js project. use that api i get random elements after template rendered.